# Subsetting a data frame based on key spanning several columns in another (summary) data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame `a` with 4 identifying columns: `A, B, C, D`. A second data frame `b`, created with `ddply()`, contains a summary of all the values for different `D`s for every set of `A,B,C`. A third data frame `c` contains a subset of `b` with bad values that I want to delete from `a`.

Thus, I want a subset from `a`, omitting all the rows identified by a combination of `A,B,C` that are also present in `c`. I can think of ways do this (ugly and inefficiently) in a loop, but, my DBA background encourages me to seek a solution that is a little bit more … direct.

In code:

```
a <- data.frame(
  A=rep(c('2013-10-30', '2014-11-6'), each=16*20),
  B=rep(1:8, each=2*20),
  C=rep(1:4, each=20),
  D=1:20
)

a$Val=rnorm(nrow(a))

library(plyr)
b <- ddply(a, ~B+C+A, summarise,
           mean_Val=mean(Val))

# Some subset criteria based on AOI group values
c <- subset(b, mean_Val <= 0)

# EDIT: Delete all the rows from a for which the
# key-triplets A,B,C are present in c
for (i in 1:nrow(c)) {
  c_row = c[i,]
  a <- a[ which( !(a$A==c_row$A & a$B==c_row$B & a$C==c_row$C) ), ]
}
# This is the loopy type of 'solution' I didn't want to use
```

Please feel free also to address unclarities in my question. I'd be happy to edit if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide some example datasets and expected result.  Also, your description is not specific.  Summary can be mean, sum, median etc..

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @akrun. I will try to include an informative part of the original dataset.

Comment: I now added a loop which creates the result in a roundabout way, in an attempt to satisfy @David's [deleted] request for the expected result data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we already created 3 datasets and want to subset the first "a" based on the elements of "c/c1", one option is `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(a, c1, by=c('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

#### Update

Or we could use a `base R` option with `interaction` to paste the columns of interest together in both datasets and check whether the elements of 2nd ('c') are in 1st ('a') using `%in%`.  The logical index can be used to subset "a".

```
 a1 <- a[!(as.character(interaction(a[1:3], sep=".")) %in% 
          as.character(interaction(c[LETTERS[1:3]], sep="."))),]
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned, we may not need to create `b`, or `c` datasets to get the expected output.  Using `plyr`, create a new mean column ("mean_Val") in "a" with `mutate` and `subset` the rows with mean greater than 0 (`mean_Val >0`)

```
 library(plyr)
 subset(ddply(a, ~B+C+A, mutate, mean_Val=mean(Val)), mean_Val>0)
```

Or a similar approach using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  a %>%
     group_by(B, C, A) %>%
     mutate(mean_Val=mean(Val)) %>% 
     filter(mean_Val>0)
```

Or if we don't need the "mean" values as a column in "a", `ave` from `base R` could be used as well.

```
  a[!!with(a, ave(Val, B, C, A, FUN=function(x) mean(x)>0)),]
```

If we need to keep the `mean_Val` column (a variation proposed by @David Arenburg)

```
  subset(transform(a, Mean_Val = ave(Val, B, C, A, FUN = mean)),
                 Mean_Val > 0)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
a <- data.frame(A= sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE), 
   B=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE), C=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 
         20, replace=TRUE), D=rnorm(20))

b <- a %>% 
       group_by(A, B, C) %>% 
       summarise(D=sum(D))
set.seed(39)
c1 <- b[sample(1:nrow(b), 6, replace=FALSE),]
```

Comment: Although `anti_join()` does seem to do what I'm looking for, the R version that I have to work with for now is too old for dplyr. I only have plyr installed.

Comment: You can keep the `Mean_Val` as a var with `ave` too as in `subset(transform(a, Mean_Val = ave(Val, B, C, A, FUN = mean)), Mean_Val > 0)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, I was trying to replicate the results of OP.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun; `interaction()` does the job just splendidly! I very much appreciate the time you put into providing and revising your answer. :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution which won't require creating neither `b` or `c`

```
library(data.table) 
as.data.table(a)[, if(mean(Val) > 0) .SD, by = list(B, C, A)]
```

Or similarly (If you also want the mean itself)

```
as.data.table(a)[, Mean_Val := mean(Val), list(B, C, A)][Mean_Val > 0]
```

Comment: I love the idea of data.table, David. Coming from a database dev. background, I have much appreciation for its apparent simplicity and power. Too bad, I'm on an old R on an old Linux, which fails to install the package, so I've accepted the base R solution by @akrun.